# How to call a VLC Player Intent With Stream url and User Agent

Tags: android, android-intent, vlc, http-live-streaming, user-agent

I am trying to create a intent which will call a `mxplayer intent` and `vlc player` intent . This intent will contain **live video link** and **user agent** . I added the url using `intent.setData()` but how to add the `user agent header` ?
 
Code :

```
String packagename = "com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setPackage(packagename);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(now.video_url));
//add the user agent header here     
// now.user_agent contains the agent link                   
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Also how to do it in vlc player , I didn't find anything in their [android-api](https://wiki.videolan.org/Android_Player_Intents/) with user-agent

My try for vlc:

```
String packagename = "org.videolan.vlc";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setPackage(packagename);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(now.video_url));

intent.putExtra("user-agent",now.user_agent);
//tried these too , doesn't work
//intent.putExtra("http-user-agent",now.user_agent);
//intent.putExtra("User-Agent",now.user_agent);
//String[] headers = {
//                            "http-user-agent", now.user_agent
//                    };
//intent.putExtra("headers",headers);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at their [API](http://mx.j2inter.com/api) I added this and it worked

```
String[] headers = {
  "User-Agent", now.user_agent
};
intent.putExtra("headers",headers);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Didn't find anything for VLC till now